# How can I find files with names that feature several times the same character?

Tags: bash, file, search, command-line

For example I have several files like:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
f1le.txt
file11.txt
11f1le.txt
1file.txt
f11le11.txt
```

In this particular case, how can I find files that have several times the digit **'1'** in their names:

```
file11.txt
11f1le.txt
f11le11.txt
```

using

```
find .
```

or

```
ls -l
```

Comment: what's wrong with piping through grep?

Comment: Professor clarified that I am limited only to ls -l and find

Comment: The starting point is going through find manpage. Have you found something helpful in there? Since it's an assignment, you should show your efforts and research.

Comment: I recommend to study the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Comment: @Quasímodo, I managed to finish several tasks related to this and this one is the only one that is left. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Cyrus, I have an idea about wildcards and I have used them to solve my previous tasks in the assignment. For this one, I just can't seem to find a proper way of writing a command. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to search for  glob

```
$ls -1 *[1][1]*
11f1le.txt
f11le11.txt
file11.txt
$find . -name  "*[1][1]*"  -type f
./file11.txt
./f11le11.txt
./11f1le.txt
$
```

`*` --> Wild card
`11`--> Character 1  follwed by 1

Comment: Besides, it won't find `1file1`, which fulfills the condition.

Comment: @oguz Ismail Thank you. I have edited the answer. Going forward won't answer questions without efforts.